# What are better substitute OSS for ElasticSearch?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, open-source

I heard ElasticSearch is already changing its license to SSPL. Because of that, it will not be considered as an OSS (OpenSource Software) anymore.

Do you know of a better OSS as replacement for ElasticSearch?

Hope suggested OSS has an official image in dockerhub since I will be using it also in Kubernetes.

Comment: you can try opendistro - https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/ from AWS. You can try the docker compose file from https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/docker/ here

Comment: Opendistro will be discontinued after Amazon forked Elasticsearch 7.10.2 as Opensearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch was on SSPL, but we moved to a simpler license. check out https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-license-v2 for details on that aspect

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/) alternative provided by AWS could be a correct possibility.
It's forked from Elasticsearch and provide the same [features](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/amazon-elasticsearch-service-is-now-amazon-opensearch-service-and-supports-opensearch-10/).

Comment: "Same features" as of 7.10.2, which was released on January 14, 2021. Since it's a fork, it's safe to assume that the features will diverge

Comment: First of all, I have edited my question. I'll be using it in Kubernetes, so at least it should have an official docker image.

Comment: Opensearch has docker images, so you can use that. As already said, Opensearch is a fork of version 7.10.2, the last OSS release of Elasticsearch and features are different already. Depending on your requirements you still can use the basic and free version of Elasticsearch if you want.